# Twilio Conversations - Do closed conversations count towards the channels per identity limit

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-conversations

In the Twilio docs, there is an option to set the state of a conversation from active, inactive, or closed. It says "Be aware that closed Conversations do not count towards the Participant-per-Conversation limit." However, I am not sure if a closed conversation counts towards the channels per identity limit (1000 in total). Can anyone clarify this? thank you

Comment: That's odd, since the number of participants in a closed conversation wouldn't matter anyway. I will check with the conversations team about what this means and clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I checked with the team and closed conversations do not count towards the channels per identity limit.

Further, I'll work to clarify that in the docs.

Comment: And the docs have been updated, thanks for bringing this to our attention @handroski!